# Updating numpy array in loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am getting some strange results from the following but am relatively new to python so may be messing something up.  The following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(a)

old_a = a

for x in range(0,1):
   new_a = old_a
   new_a[0] = old_a[1]
   new_a[1] = old_a[2]
   new_a[2] = old_a[3]
   new_a[3] = old_a[0]
   print(new_a)

[1 2 3 4]
[2 3 4 2]
```

I would have expected the second array to be [2 3 4 1].

However, if I create a new array as with the "clean" def below, it seems to work

```
def clean(b_in):
   out = np.zeros(4)
   for x in range(0,4):
       out[x] = b_in[x]
   return out

b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(b)

new_b = b

for x in range(0,1):
   old_b = clean(new_b)
   new_b[0] = old_b[1]
   new_b[1] = old_b[2]
   new_b[2] = old_b[3]
   new_b[3] = old_b[0]
   print(new_b) 

[1 2 3 4]
[2 3 4 1]
```

What am I missing and how do I avoid the clean def?

Thanks

**** Updated question below ****

Thanks for the responses.  So, notwithstanding the response regarding the roll function below, is this the best way to do achieve the same as the roll function?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(a)

old_a = a

for x in range(0,10):
   new_a = old_a.copy()
   new_a[0] = old_a[1]
   new_a[1] = old_a[2]
   new_a[2] = old_a[3]
   new_a[3] = old_a[0]
   old_a = new_a.copy()
   print(new_a)
```

Thanks again

**EDIT**

This is what I settled on:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(a)

old_a = a
new_a = np.zeros_like(old_a)

for x in range(0,10):
    new_a[0] = old_a[1]
    new_a[1] = old_a[2]
    new_a[2] = old_a[3]
    new_a[3] = old_a[0]
    old_a = new_a.copy()
    print(new_a)

[1 2 3 4]
[2 3 4 1]
[3 4 1 2]
[4 1 2 3]
[1 2 3 4]
[2 3 4 1]
[3 4 1 2]
[4 1 2 3]
[1 2 3 4]
[2 3 4 1]
[3 4 1 2]
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Your assignment `new_a = old_a` is the problem, as `new_a` points now to the same memory as `old_a`. If you want to copy a `numpy` array, use `new_a = old_a.copy()`.

Comment: Furthermore, as you are overwriting all elements anyhow, you don't need to copy, but you can create an array of zeros of the same shape with `new_b = np.zeros_like(old_b)`, or an empty array with `new_b = np.empty_like(old_b)`.

Comment: No, you are making an unnecessary copy in the first line under `for`. It is better to declare `new_a` outside of the loop, then one copy suffices. And please use four spaces :).

Comment: @Austin check the updated answer for a better way of doing this

Comment: Ah, got it now.  Thanks a lot, Chiel

Comment: no need to maintain the extra variable `new_a` @Austin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're changing the values of `new_a` you're also changing the values of `old_a` as you're doing shallow copy and not deepcopy by assigning `new_a = old_a`:

```
new_a[0] = old_a[1]
new_a[1] = old_a[2]
new_a[2] = old_a[3]
#old_a[0] is already old_a[1], as you reassigned it on line #1
new_a[3] = old_a[0]
```

Here's the difference between shallow and deepcopy as in [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
>   A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

You can avoid your clean def by using `deepcopy` or `copy()` in case of numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
#from copy import deepcopy #for python lists
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(a)
old_a = a
for x in range(0,1):
   #new_a = deepcopy(old_a) #for python lists
   new_a = old_a.copy() # for numpy array
   new_a[0] = old_a[1]
   new_a[1] = old_a[2]
   new_a[2] = old_a[3]
   new_a[3] = old_a[0]
   print(new_a)
```

**EDIT**

After your updated question, looks like you want to update the `old_a` itself, so no need to `copy` it to new array, you can simply achieve what you're trying to do like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(a)
old_a = a
for x in range(0,1):
   old_a[0], old_a[1], old_a[2], old_a[3] = old_a[1], old_a[2], old_a[3], old_a[0]
   print(old_a)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use `deepcopy` here. Numpy has its own copy function that is readily available. See my comment above.

Comment: ohh forgot he's using numpy, updated the answer thanks :)

Comment: @AshishRanjan -- why do you need a 'for' loop?

Comment: OP needs it, I don't @Merlin

Comment: @AshishRanjan look at OP code, he does not use "x"!

Comment: @Merlin but that's what he has written in the question, maybe in a larger codebase he does

Comment: @AshishRanjan It should be pointed out to a newbie that he does need the 'for' loop.

Comment: @Merlin why not, if he wants to perform this operation `n` times, then surely he'll want to use it, won't he? he's doing it indeed, in the updated question

Comment: @AshishRanjan, read the code OP is doing the same thing 10 times!. OP does not need to do this 10x or even once.

Comment: @Merlin you're saying like you've the access to OP's codebase maybe he wants to do anything else in the loop and just shared a part of their code here, how can you so safely assume he doesn't need the loop? Anyways, no point in discussing, the question was to help him with `what is he missing` and that's has been figured out nicely :)

Answer (score 2):

Even though this answer is not answering your question, for your specific case there is a much simpler solution, if shifting the elements by one is what you are searching for. It avoids the complexity in which you are getting stuck, and it simplifies things.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.roll(a, -1)
print(a, b)
```

Output

```
[1 2 3 4] [2 3 4 1]
```

Comment: For the downvoter: I know it is not an answer to the question exactly, and I have already given my comments under the post. I just thought to give a tip on how to address this specific case in the best `numpy` way.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you understand what you are doing:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(a)

old_a = a

for x in range(0,1):
    new_a = old_a
    new_a[0] = old_a[1]
    print  new_a
    new_a[1] = old_a[2]
    print  new_a
    new_a[2] = old_a[3]
    print  new_a
    new_a[3] = old_a[0]
    print(new_a)

[1 2 3 4]
[2 2 3 4]
[2 3 3 4]
[2 3 4 4]
[2 3 4 2]
```

So when you do this `new_a[3] = old_a[0]`, position `O` is already "2". 
Below gives you what you expected.

```
for x in range(0,1):
    new_a = old_a.copy()
    new_a[0] = old_a[1]
    print  new_a
    new_a[1] = old_a[2]
    print  new_a
    new_a[2] = old_a[3]
    print  new_a
    new_a[3] = old_a[0]
    print(new_a)

[1 2 3 4]
[2 2 3 4]
[2 3 3 4]
[2 3 4 4]
[2 3 4 1]
```

The fastest way to do this is 'fancy' indexing :

```
a     = np.array([1,2,3,4])
new_a = a[np.array([1,2,3,0])]
print new_a

array([2, 3, 4, 1])
```

Comment: I will post below

Comment: Of course, will do but I dont have the 15 reputation yet to make it public.  Thanks again